# Get the latest block number of a contract

Tags: ethereum, web3js

How do I get the block number of the latest confirmed transaction in a contract?

Context:

web3's `myContract.getPastEvents` allows you to set the blockNumber from which you will start fetching the events. But I haven't come across a way to find out the latest blockNumber for a contract.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by the "latest block number for a contract?" The most recent block in which the contract was modified? Or something else?

Comment: @smarx Sorry, should've been clearer. I meant to say the block number of the most recently confirmed transaction in a contract.

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way to do that. Why do you want to?

Comment: @smarx I want to start polling for future events, starting from the latest confirmed block in a contract. I tried using websocket with infura node to catch events but the behavior has been inconsistent, so I had to resort to getPastEvents.

Comment: Why don't you just start from the current block?

Comment: @smarx Oh! Do you mean the current block of entire ethereum, not just the current blockchain?

Comment: I don't know what "the current blockchain" means. I mean the latest block in Ethereum. `web3.eth.getBlockNumber`

Comment: Thank you! That should work. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can select it? Also, do you recommend doing it this way to poll events? Do you have experience with websockets by any chance?

Comment: I haven't used websockets yet; all my event monitoring thus far has been via MetaMask in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the discussion in comments, there's no need to find the most recent block involving the contract; you can simply start from the most recent block, period:

```
web3.eth.getBlockNumber(function (err, blockNumber) { ... });
```

Comment: Could you change the callback argument to (err, blockNumber)?

Comment: Done. Thank you.